# Unable to get the error and check if it exist

Tags: perl, wmic

I am trying to access a server and get its name but it is not available how can i deal with the error and continue with the rest of the script.If this command `qx($srvername)`  returns an error i want to exit the `for` loop

```
my @s =qw(v200 pm363   wq280 );
foreach $a (@s){

  eval {
  my $srvername="wmic /node: '$a' computersystem get Name";
  my $opt = qx($srvername) ;

  if($!){ 
     next;
  }
 };


print "here$a\n";   
}
```

Comment: The `$?` ([$CHILD_ERROR](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24CHILD_ERROR)) gives the status. It should be zero if all went well.  Read [in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the `$opt` variable outside of the `eval` block if you want to use it. You also need to do the `next` outside of the `eval` block.

I've changed a bunch of things around your code.

We now declare `$opt` and `$srvername` outside of the `eval`. It's better to scope the `eval` as small as possible, and creating a string will not fail.

We then call the `qx()` inside of the `eval`, and assign `$opt`, which is scoped inside the `foreach` block. That way you can access it afterwards.

If the `qx` fails, we `die`, which breaks out of the `eval` block. If you care about the error that `qx` threw, you can throw [`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%3f).

After the `eval` we check [`$@`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%40), wich holds the eval error. If something is in there (probably our `$?` from the `qx`), we go to the `next` iteration.

```
my @s = qw( v200 pm363 wq280 );
foreach my $node ( @s ){
  my $opt;
  my $srvername = "wmic /node: '$node' computersystem get Name";

  eval {
    $opt = qx($srvername) or die $?;
  };

  next if $@;

  print "$node - opt\n";   
}
```

Note that I also renamed `$a` to `$node`. The variable name `$a` is reserved for `sort` along with `$b`. It's also a good idea to give your variables meaningful names that speak for themselves.